# Will this change the meaning of the sentence?

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary

In this sentence:

> You can send e-mails to targeted photo buyers and include a link to your website.

If I change the word 'targeted' to 'target', will this make any changes to the meaning of the sentence? Or, will it be grammatically incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

If you change *targeted* to *target*, the sentence will remain grammatical—at least so long as it's parsed in an appropriate way.

This is a grammatical parsing of the sentence (the words in parentheses do not need to be there; I have added them only to clarify the interpretation).

> ✔ You can <sup>send e-mails (in order) to target photo buyers</sup> and  <sup>(you can) include a link to your website.</sup>

---

By changing *targeted* to *target*, you change the adjective to a verb. This does change the meaning; it adds additional information about the intention behind the sending of the emails. But it doesn't make the sentence ungrammatical.

---

Note that it's also possible to interpret *target* as an attributive noun. (In other words, a noun that acts as an adjective.)

In other words:

> You can send e-mails to target photo buyers.
>
> → You can send e-mails to buyers of *photos of targets*.

I don't personally think this would be as common an interpretation (at least I find it a bit awkward) but it's still possible.

---

It's also been pointed out to me in a comment that *target photo buyers* could be used in the same sense as *target audience*.

To me, that's the least likely interpretation, but it's not impossible. While *target audience* is a common set phrase, using *target X* (where *X* is a different noun) is not nearly as common.

Even that change would be grammatical. And while it wouldn't change the meaning nearly as much as the others, a *target audience* is a bit different than a *targeted audience*, and, by extension, so would *target photo buyers* be different than *targeted photo buyers*. One refers to a past tense action (although it's still an adjective) and the other is a simple attributive noun.

Comment: I think you can use target as an adjective as in “target buyers” or “target audience”. *You can send emails to target buyers* can be ambiguous though. *You can send e-mail to your target buyers...* might work.

Comment: @ColleenV Yes, you're right. And I even thought of a third interpretation. I have updated my answer to include this.

Answer (score -3):

It would be grammatically incorrect. "Target" is not an adjective. "Targeted" is.

If you wish to use the word "target," you must use it as a verb.

> You can target certain photo buyers and send them an email that includes a link to your website.

Comment: What if it is used like that in the sentence: "The 'target' audience for the TV series is young people aged 13 to 18."?

Comment: I read "target photo buyers" as people who buy photos of targets. But "You can send e-mails to target photo buyers" is also valid (with "target" as a verb): in order to target people who buy photos, you can send e-mails.